# Erro duarante o commit no git

Tags: git, commit

Errei ao digitar um comando no git:

**git commit -m inicialcommit*

Recebi essa mensagem, porém não sei o que significa.

```
C:\Users\alex.jose.silva\Documents\demo2 (master -> origin)
λ git commit -m inicialcommit
[master (root-commit) 25dd6f5] inicialcommit
 20 files changed, 970 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 demo/.gitignore
 create mode 100644 demo/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
 create mode 100644 demo/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties
 create mode 100644 demo/bin/.gitignore
 create mode 100644 demo/bin/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
 create mode 100644 demo/bin/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties
 create mode 100644 demo/bin/mvnw
 create mode 100644 demo/bin/mvnw.cmd
 create mode 100644 demo/bin/pom.xml
 create mode 100644 demo/bin/src/main/java/com/developer/demo/DemoApplication.class
 create mode 100644 demo/bin/src/main/resources/application.properties
 create mode 100644 demo/bin/src/test/java/com/developer/demo/DemoApplicationTests.class
 create mode 100644 demo/mvnw
 create mode 100644 demo/mvnw.cmd
 create mode 100644 demo/pom.xml
 create mode 100644 demo/src/main/java/com/developer/demo/DemoApplication.java
 create mode 100644 demo/src/main/resources/application.properties
 create mode 100644 demo/src/main/resources/static/index.html
 create mode 100644 demo/src/main/resources/templates/tela.html
 create mode 100644 demo/src/test/java/com/developer/demo/DemoApplicationTests.java
```

Comment: Está parecendo que você *comitou*...

Comment: os arquivos estão integros ??

Answer (score 2):

O que aconteceu foi que você gerou um commit com a mensagem "inicialcommit" para a sua árvore de commits. Essa mensagem apenas mostra quantos arquivos foram modificados, quantas inserções, quantas deleções e quais os arquivos foram commitados.

Answer (score 0):

O commit de fato aconteceu! Nesse caso, foram 20 arquivos modificados e mais de 970 inserções. Agora é só dar um `git push` pra enviar ao servidor as modificações.